# Java JNLP Applet on window close don't stop

Tags: java, applet, jnlp

I've migrated a applet launch with html applet tag to a jnlp deployment, with applet descriptor.

With the applet solution, when the browser window is closed, the java aplication ends.

With the JNLP solution, when window is closed, the java application don't stop.
And exception is raised :

```
Plugin2Manager calling stopFailed() because of exception during AppContext.dispose()
Plugin2Manager calling stopFailed() because of displayable window         javax.swing.JFrame[frame0,240,1,1018x647,invalid,hidden,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=TimeCheck,normal,defaultCloseOperation=HIDE_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,3,32,1012x612,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]
Exception in thread "Thread-19" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.destroyAppContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.destroyAppContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.cleanupAppContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.shutdownAppContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.stop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.viewer.JNLP2Viewer$2$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a WindowListener to the topLevel Frame. Once we have the TopLevel Frame it is also possible to set Resizable.

```
    ....
    while (parent.getParent() != null)
        parent = parent.getParent();
        if (parent instanceof Frame) {
            ((Frame) parent).setResizable(true);
            ((Frame) parent).addWindowListener(this);
    }
    ....
```

The event handler for the close event will execute a System.exit();

```
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.exit(0);
}
```